# GetKeyboardState for foreground window

Tags: c#, winapi

How can i get the keyboard state of foreground window ?
i have searched for that but nothing helpful

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);
```

get the current application keyboard state not an external window (the active one)

***UPDATE***
i have done as slashy says but still get nothing but when do as i understood still got nothing so could any one tell me whats wrong with this code

```
 public static char GetCharFromKey(Key key)
        {
            char ch = ' ';

            int virtualKey = KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(key);


            uint x = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);


            uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey((uint)virtualKey, MapType.MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(2);

            int result = ToUnicode((uint)virtualKey, scanCode, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetKeyboardLayout(x).ToString()), stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity, 0);

            switch (result)
            {
                case -1:
                    break;
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    {
                        ch = stringBuilder[0];
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        ch = stringBuilder[0];
                        break;
                    }
            }

            return ch;
        }
```

still get my application keyboard state not the foreground

Comment: By active window I guess you actually mean foreground window

Comment: What do you mean by *keyboard state* for *active window*? `GetKeyboardState` returns 256 virtual keys' statuses. So if, say, *SHIFT* is pressed it is pressed for *all* the windows.

Comment: of course foreground

Comment: yup dmitry but if i used global hook with it the GetKeyboardState just return keyboard state of my application but not the foreground window

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Keyboard state is maintained by the system **per thread** (or group of attached threads).

Comment: @HansPassant how could this help me becuase it's the first time i saw this function could you plz aleast give me an example that show usage of it

Comment: Call AttachThreadInput as said by @HansPassant to attach your thread, `GetCurrentThreadId` to the thread of the foreground window, gotten by `GetForegroundWindow` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, then when you call `GetKeyboardState` you will get the keyboard state of the foreground window as suggested by @IInspectable.

Answer (score -2):

You should get the window handler first, then find the keyboard state:

**Dll imports**

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);
```

Code:

```
uint x = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);

  keyboard = GetKeyboardLayout(x).ToString();//holds the state
```

Comment: I'd assume, because it doesn't even attempt to answer the question. The question is asking for keyboard **state**. You have answered how to get the keyboard **layout**.

Comment: Sorry for that @slashy but it does not solve my problem it still get state or my application not foreground and i realy don't know why !